# Citation with some text inside square brackets

Tags: citing

I'd like to add a citation which looks like this:

```
[_Text_ Citation_01, pages]
```

For example:

```
[See: 155, pp.89--99]
```

How can I do this using **standard** `\cite{}` command (without `natbib` or anything else)?

**P.S. The text might be in Cyrillic!**

Comment: Please, can you add some more information about what you're using for citations? Just the default LaTeX commands or `natbib` or whatever?

Comment: @egreg, just standard \cite{} command, nothing special

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A recommendable choice would be to use `natbib` or better yet `biblatex`. Let's see with `natbib`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{01,
 author={Caesar, Gaius Iulius},
 title={Commentarii de bello {Gallico}},
 year={703},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}

\begin{document}

Here's a citation \cite[See:][p.~2]{01}

Another: \cite[p.~3]{01}.

Another: \cite{01}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `\cite` command has now two optional argument. When only one is present, it's the "post-citation"; if two are present, the first is the "pre-citation" and the second one the post-citation.

Without extra packages you can still emulate this behavior:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{01,
 author={Caesar, Gaius Iulius},
 title={Commentarii de bello {Gallico}},
 year={703},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\cite\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cite}{%
  \let\new@cite@pre\@gobble
  \@ifnextchar[\new@cite{\@citex[]}}
\def\new@cite[#1]{\@ifnextchar[{\new@citea{#1}}{\@citex[#1]}}
\def\new@citea#1{\def\new@cite@pre{#1}\@citex}
\def\@cite#1#2{[{\new@cite@pre\space#1\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else, #2\fi}]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here's a citation \cite[See:][p.~2]{01}

Another: \cite[p.~3]{01}.

Another: \cite{01}.

Again: \cite[See:][]{01}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

In case you want only the "pre-citation", use

```
\cite[See:][]{01}
```

with an empty second optional argument.

[image]

Comment: @egreg, +1. Professional solution.

Comment: Just one more thing... How to modify this code (the part which doesn't use extra packages) in order to make a citation [See: 1], that is, WITHOUT page number(s)?

Comment: @Physicsworks I'd prefer the `natbib` solution; however I've added also the "package free" version.

Comment: @egreg, I've already tried this, unfortunately, it adds a comma after citation number, so it looks like this: [See: 1,]. P.S. Sorry, I need this to be done without extra packages...

Comment: @Physicsworks I changed the code. With the present version no extra comma is added.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about a new command `\Cite`

```
\newcommand{\Cite}[2]{[See~\cite{#1},~#2]}
```

Comment: This adds the text AFTER Citation_01, not before, as I'd like to have

Comment: I believe that "155" in the OP's question refers to the number automatically generated by `\cite`.

Comment: @egreg, you're right

Comment: Oh, I see. My fault. Edited.

Comment: @Sigur, Thanks, it works, although it adds extra []

Answer (score 2):

I'm sometimes required to use `amsrefs` and have been looking for something analogous to `natbib`'s built-in `\cite[pre][post]{label}` for a while. Since I haven't seen it online or in the package documentation (as of 2018), I'm posting the solution here.

It turns out you can just write pre-citation and/or post-citation text inside a `\citelist` command, i.e., `\citelist{cf. \cite{morgan-tian}}` prints out: [cf. MT].

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortalphabetic]{amsrefs}

\begin{document}
Theorem 1 follows from 
Lemma 2 \cite{morgan-tian}*{1.1} and 
Proposition 3 \citelist{cf. \cite{morgan-tian}*{1.2}}.

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{morgan-tian}{book}{
  author={Morgan, John},
  author={Tian, Gang},
  title={Ricci flow and the Poincar\'e conjecture},
  series={Clay Mathematics Monographs},
  volume={3},
  publisher={American Mathematical Society},
  place={Providence, RI},
  date={2007},
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, natbib or biblatex are the way to go. But if you have restrictions like me, you could try this option, which I think is a little easier to understand than the other answers here.

I couldn't get the usual precitation `\cite[See: ][]{Citation_01}` to work for my case, which is an IEEE computer society (compsoc) conference paper - although it has worked for me in the past with other formats. The prescribed preamble includes: `\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}`.

I ended up going with this hack:

```
\renewcommand\citeleft{[See:~}
...as proven in~\cite{Citation_01}. 
\renewcommand\citeleft{[}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it has been a while I would like to suggest a solution which I used for my `\cite` problem. In our documentation we should cite our reference documents as [RD-n] and for applicable documents [AD-n]. So here is my solution for that:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifkeyword{RD}{RD-#1}{AD-#1}}
```

My example .bib file for RDs:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "RD"
}

@book{dirac,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {RD}
}

@online{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "RD"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    year = "1973",
    chapter = "1.2",
    keywords  = "RD"
}
```

Above solution provides me to identify if the keyword in .bib declared as "RD" then `\cite{dirac}` or `\cite{<your_cite>}` command prints out [RD-1] or [RD-n].

It is processing for ADs same as RDs.

Example .bib for ADs:

```
@book{onur,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {AD}
}

@book{sergio,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {AD}
}

@book{ivan,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {AD}
}
```

Same as RDs we should only type `\cite{<your_cite>}`. Since our (company) applicable documents are not cite-able we are using `\nocite*{<AD document keyword>}` at the preamble of the document. Such as just after the `\begin{document}` command.

I hope this helps for anyone!