# Citation with text inside brackets, and with semicolon

Tags: citing

My question is very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89143/citation-with-some-text-inside-square-brackets).  Using a portion of the accepted answer as a reference in my question,

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{01,
 author={Caesar, Gaius Iulius},
 title={Commentarii de bello {Gallico}},
 year={703},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\cite\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cite}{%
  \let\new@cite@pre\@gobble
  \@ifnextchar[\new@cite{\@citex[]}}
\def\new@cite[#1]{\@ifnextchar[{\new@citea{#1}}{\@citex[#1]}}
\def\new@citea#1{\def\new@cite@pre{#1}\@citex}
\def\@cite#1#2{[{\new@cite@pre\space#1\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else, #2\fi}]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here's a citation \cite[See:][p.~2]{01}

Another: \cite[p.~3]{01}.

Another: \cite{01}.

Again: \cite[See:][]{01}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

produces 
[image]

However, instead of commas for the first two lines in the rendered document, I would instead like semicolons.  How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

The `,` is in the definition of `\@cite`, the last line before `\makeatother`, just af the `\else`.  Replace that comma with a semicolon:

[image: Sample output]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{01,
 author={Caesar, Gaius Iulius},
 title={Commentarii de bello {Gallico}},
 year={703},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\cite\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cite}{%
  \let\new@cite@pre\@gobble
  \@ifnextchar[\new@cite{\@citex[]}}
\def\new@cite[#1]{\@ifnextchar[{\new@citea{#1}}{\@citex[#1]}}
\def\new@citea#1{\def\new@cite@pre{#1}\@citex}
\def\@cite#1#2{[{\new@cite@pre\space#1\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else; #2\fi}]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here's a citation \cite[See:][p.~2]{01}

Another: \cite[p.~3]{01}.

Another: \cite{01}.

Again: \cite[See:][]{01}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

By the way `bibtex` warns that there is a missing publisher for this work :-)