# Add Text after citation, without comma

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am relatively new to latex and just learned that there is a natbib package.

Im trying to add a citation with Text behind it:
I know `\cite[Text]{key}` exists. But that produces: **[Key, Text]** in my case.

Is there a way to add text behind the citation without using the comma? I'm trying to reference the same source but with different numbers: **[ITI-16]**, **[ITI-42]**, while enclosed in brackets.

I think I need to adjust the settings like answered here [Citation with some text inside square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89143/citation-with-some-text-inside-square-brackets). If thats true, please explain how I should move forward in my case.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Thank you! I think its **geralpha**, does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're employing the `natbib` citation management package, I suggest you use

```
\setcitestyle{notesep={-}}
```

to set the desired connector. (The default is `\setcitestyle{notesep={, }}`.) See section 2.9 of the user guide of the `natbib` package for more information about the `\setcitestyle` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={-}} % <-- new
\bibliographystyle{geralpha}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{iti,
  author = "Iti",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 2001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite[16]{iti}, \cite[42]{iti}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```