# bibliography settings

Tags: biblatex, bibliographystyle

I would like to cite a reference In my text but instead of having [1] I want [Duan] but I can find a way. I tried in this way:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

....

\cite{Duan}
```

and in the biblio.bib I have:

```
@article{Duan,


  keywords = {Duan},

  title={ The GARCH Option Pricing Model},

  author={Duan, Jin-Chuan},

  journal={Mathematical finance},

  year={1995},

  number = "5",

  DOI = "https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9965.1995.tb00099.x"

}
```

Comment: Are you potentially looking for `usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}`?

Comment: It gives [Dua95] but I want [Duan] as the keywords

Comment: That is an interesting citation style. I am not sure how you would access the keywords in a citation (it is probably possible, I just don't know). However, if this is always the first author, you could define a command `\newcommand{\mycite}{[\citeauthor*{#1}]}` and use this for citations. You will also have to redefine the `\andothers`-string to an empty string if you have works with more than one author. I did not test this, but I am pretty sure it gets you at least close to what you want.

Comment: This [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585165/231548) may help you.